# How To Find The Right Formula

Tags: mathematical-statistics, scales

First off, I'm kind of out of my element when it comes to formulas and figuring out how to come up with a formula for what I need. If you need any other information, let me know and I'll add it.

**Scenario:**

I need to determine the opacity percentage of these elements that I'm plotting on a map. Now, my scale of **0-100** is really **0.05-0.85**. It's relative to the number of days since an event has happened. Meaning, if an event happened 0 days ago, the opacity should be **0.05**, and if an event happened 365 days ago, the opacity should be **0.85**. How do I form a formula to get the values in between?

Comment: This is answered in a few hundred posts, directly or indirectly.  The duplicate has one of the higher voted answers I could find quickly.  For more, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normalize.